# Drool resource url not able to read data from s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, drools

I am trying to implement drool engine I have uploaded my xlsx file on my s3 bucket the issue comes when I try to get file from my s3 folder the code breaks and moves to catch block and the file is read from local resource folder.I am not able to identify the issue don't know what is wrong with my code If I make my folder public then I am easily able to access the file.I have use two approach
Approach 1

```
  @Configuration
public class DroolsAutoConfiguration {
    
    private static final String RULES_PATH = "rules/";
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KieFileSystem.class)
    public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() throws IOException {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = getKieServices().newKieFileSystem();
            kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource("s3url"));
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KieContainer.class)
    public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {
        KieServices kieServices =  getKieServices();
        final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        
        kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
            @Override
            public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
                return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
            }
        });
        
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem());
        Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
        if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            System.out.println(results.getMessages());
            throw new IllegalStateException("### errors ###");
        }

        kieBuilder.buildAll();

        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
        KieUtils.setKieContainer(kieContainer);
        return kieContainer;
    }
    
    private KieServices getKieServices() {
        return KieServices.Factory.get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KieBase.class)
    public KieBase kieBase() throws IOException {
        return kieContainer().getKieBase();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.class)
    public KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor kiePostProcessor() {
        return new KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Approach 2

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DroolConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;


    private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    public KieFileSystem getKieFileSystem() throws IOException {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        Resource dt;
        try {
            dt= ResourceFactory
                    .newUrlResource("S3 URL");
        }catch (Exception e){
            dt= ResourceFactory
                    .newClassPathResource("localfile.xlsx");
        }
        kieFileSystem.write(dt);
        DecisionTableProviderImpl decisionTableProvider
                = new DecisionTableProviderImpl();

        String drl = decisionTableProvider.loadFromResource(dt, null);
        log.info("*************"+drl);
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer getKieContainer() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Container created...");
        getKieRepository();
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(getKieFileSystem());
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        return kContainer;
    }

    private void getKieRepository() {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
            public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
                return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public KieSession getKieSession() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("session created...");
        return getKieContainer().newKieSession();
    }

}
```

Approach 2 works fine even if the bucket is private can anyone tell me what is the issue with first approach

Comment: AmazonS3 is the old API V1 API  and this is not best practice. You should consider upgrading to AWS SDK for Java V2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html

Comment: Also you say you hit the catch block but you neglect to give us the details of the error.

Comment: The error is “no resource found in s3 bucket”

Comment: The difference between the two approaches is that you have autowired the AmazonS3 client in the second approach. It's probably helping to resolve that URL, though I couldn't say for certain because I'm a drools person not an AWS person. (This really doesn't have very much of anything to do with Drools, really, regardless of the tags.)